# How to retrieve an arraylist from Managed Beans in JSF

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsf

I am quite new to `JSF` and just started reading through some tutorials about it. I have created a `JSP` page and `Managed Beans` class and got the application run successfully. Based on my simple understanding, the JSF generates the JSP file as `HTML/CSS` for the user. Here is my code:

```
public calss Beans
{
private ArrayList<String> objectString = new ArrayList<String>();
private JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
private JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();

// Fill the two arrays 
public void fill()
{
}
public void setJSON(JSONArray jsonArr)
{
    this.jsonArr = jsonArr;
}

public JSONArray getJSON()
{
    return jsonArr;
}
public void setObjectString(ArrayList<String> objectString)
{
    this.objectString = objectString;
}

public ArrayList<String> getobjectString()
{
    return objectString;
}
}
```

My question is, in `JSP`, how can I get the arrays in the `managed beans` as they are without having the HTML tags. Should I use `JSONArray` and parse it? Here is my code for `JSP`:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{beans.objectString}" var="object">
      <h:column>
          <h:outputText value="#{object}"/>
      </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

In this code, the `objectString` is shown correctly as one column. I just want to get that arraylist as an array in Javascriopt as I need it for some other work. I tried to use the JSONArray but got the problem. Could anyone please help me with this issue. Your assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I am sorry, but are you trying to use JSP or JSF? Because it seems you're using JSF tags, so I think you should instead create a xhtml file and add your JSF code up there. JSF is basically a servlet that intercepts the http requests and process them following a specific order (the JSF page lifecycle I guess). JSP, on the other hand, is a templating technology that is converted by the container to a equivalent servlet. These are two different things.

Comment: Of course, we can help you with both technologies, but it seems you still have to tell us what you're trying to do :-)

Comment: Thank you. Well. Actually I was trying to use Javascipt to create a variable with JSON format to use for displaying a graph using D3 Javascript. I just started learning all that and would like to get that array as it is.

Comment: if you're intending to just feed and consume JSON objects from and to the server side (maybe because you have a heavily-powered javascript frontend), probably you can just use barebones Servlets + JSON (GSON or flexjson or any other JSON library). JSP and JSF are for fancy web UIs :-)

Comment: I was thinking of calling the arraylist from JSP and iterate over the elements of that array within a Javascript function for example. Is that possible?

Comment: certainly. see my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. I will run it and get back to you soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSP example - JSONExample.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="mypackage.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="flexjson.JSONSerializer.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<%
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    String json = new JsonArrayGenerator(id).getJsonArray();
%>

<script>
var array = <%=json%>;
alert(array.toString());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the generator

```
package mypackage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import flexjson.JSONSerializer;


public class JsonArrayGenerator {
    private String id;

    public JsonArrayGenerator(String id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getJsonArray(){
        //some list of things
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(this.id);
        list.add(new Date());
        list.add("Hello");

        //now serialize
        JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
        String json = serializer.serialize(list);

        return json;
    }
}
```

or the other way to get a JSON array using servlets

```
package mypackage;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import flexjson.JSONSerializer;

@WebServlet("/JSONExample")
public class JSONExample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JSONExample() {
    super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String id = request.getParameter("id");

        //use the id to retrieve the list you want

        //some list of things
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(id);
        list.add(new Date());
        list.add("Hello");

        //now serialize
        JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
        String json = serializer.serialize(list);
        response.setContentType("application/json");

        //print it
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write(json);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Supposing that you're going to deploy to an app called Test, the URLs are

```
http://yourserver/Test/JSONExample (servlet)
```

and

```
http://yourserver/Test/JSONExample.jsp (JSP)
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your help. May you please tell me what the id string represent in this code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: actually, the id itself is useless in this code :-) but my idea was to show you that you could pass a parameter to the JSP file via GET (like http://yourserver/app/page.jsp?id=666) so you could use it to retrieve the java array that you want to convert to JSON.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. One more question please, when you send a request like what you did with your solution, does that necessarily mean that the response should be in Json or XML format?

Comment: This decision is up to you. In this case, I am serializing everything into JSON using JSONSerializer. If XML is what you need, then you have to use a XML serializer (such as http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) and change "response.setContentType("application/json")" into "response.setContentType("application/xml")". If you're going to work with javascript, JSON is probably the best option for you.